# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28 and 35 on Facebook apps

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, curl

I randomly get following error. It doesn't happen everytimes.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 28: Operation timed out after 60 seconds with 47 out of 47 bytes received
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out!
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
```

What I did try are

```
1. adding CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => 3 (even try changing to 2)
2. changing 'https://api-read.facebook.com/' to 'api_read'  => 'https://api.facebook.com/'
3. adding   $opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;                                          
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
4. Changing CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => from 10 to 60
5. closing IPv6 and add 69.171.224.54   graph.facebook.com to /etc/hosts (several other IPs also added)
6. telnet graph.facebook.com 443 and nslookup graph.facebook.com
```

I don't know where to look further. Please help!

FYI: cURL support = enabled, cURL Information = 7.15.5, OpenSSL Version = 0.9.8e (latest i can update on Centos 5.7)

Comment: i have same issue, it is very sparse and random, happens with cURL, and with php-sdk, and it seems to happen for any type of call.
/pageid
/pageid/feed
pageid/albums  etc;

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/328399317246454?browse=search_4ff4817e0c5ec9768956669

Comment: @Carter do you find any solution yet?

Comment: there is an open bug related and is high priorty https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335732253172491?browse=search_4ff75f44edcac2200632441
Intermitent SSL certificate errors: "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: You are saying the bug reported is related to the curlexception 28 and 35?

Comment: 35 is SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443 which would be a failure to create ssl channel.

Comment: the timout is thrown when a connection is not made is the set time allowed, base_facebook.php

  /**
   * Default options for curl.
   */
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 15,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.1',
  );

Answer (score 3):

All of these errors relate to the connection timing out during various phases of the HTTP process:

- in the first, the connection was established, but no (or very little) data was returned
- in the second, the connection couldn't be established at all
- in the third, the TCP connection was established, but was dropped somewhere in the negotiation of a secure channel

As Shawn E. Carter says above, this bug appears to be the same issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/328399317246454?browse=search_4ff4817e0c5ec9768956669 as is this question [Can not connect to Facebook with a curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088320/can-not-connect-to-facebook-with-a-curl-request?rq=1)

Ultimately, it just means that Facebook's API server was a little slower than expected. You could try using a longer timeout, or, since it's intermittent, catching the exception and trying again.